# Script not printing error in JavaScript Chrome console

Tags: javascript

I have just spent far too long trying to find a problem with the code below.

In turned out that because of the context that `addRoute` was called in, `keys()` was not returning the keys of the results object. To fix this I had to use `Object.keys()` despite it working without a problem in the JavaScript console (which I later realised was because of the context).

My question is, why didn't this show in my JavaScript console? It took me quite a while to realise (I have cropped the full code, the actual function is a lot bigger).

*Wrong, but no error in the console:*

```
Map.prototype.addRoute = function (results) {
    var sectionsIDs = keys(results);
}
```

*Correct*

```
Map.prototype.addRoute = function (results) {
    var sectionsIDs = Object.keys(results);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first function uses the [`keys` console API function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#keysobject).

That "[Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)" page includes the warning:

> **Note:** This API is only available from within the console itself. You cannot access the Command Line API from scripts on the page.

Thus, it is by design that the `keys` function only exists for code run directly on the console.

Chrome gives you a small hint about the `keys` function being a console-only function if you view it in the console:

```
 > keys  
 function keys(object) { [Command Line API] }
```